# How do you edit the collison like this?

Tags: gazebo-11, collision

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Here is the picture:
[image: image description]

I edited the code many time:

```
  <link name='head'>
  <visual name='visual'>
    <pose>0.090 0 0.16 0 0 0</pose>
    <geometry>
      <cylinder>
        <radius>0.01</radius>
        <length>0.02</length>
      </cylinder>
    </geometry>
  </visual>
   <collision name='collision'>
    <laser_retro>0</laser_retro>
    <pose >0.090 0 0.16 0 0 0</pose>
    <geometry>
      <cylinder>
        <radius>0.01</radius>
        <length>0.02</length>
      </cylinder>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
</link>
```

I edited the pose under collision code yet nothing change. Do you know why?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/27248/how-do-you-edit-the-collison-like-this?/) by [kakcalu13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51973/kakcalu13/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 87 on 2021-08-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

FOund the issue.

This is the correct:

```
  <link name="head">
  <pose >0.090 0 0.16 0 0 0</pose>
  <collision name="collision">
    <pose >0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
    <geometry>
      <cylinder>
        <radius>0.01</radius>
        <length>0.02</length>
      </cylinder>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
  <visual name="visual">
    <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
    <geometry>
      <cylinder>
        <radius>0.01</radius>
        <length>0.02</length>
      </cylinder>
    </geometry>
  </visual>
</link>
```

Closing this one

P.S.
all of my posts required moderation to approve. Not sure why.

---

Originally posted by [kakcalu13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51973/kakcalu13/) with karma: 87 on 2021-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0